# How to optimise below sql query

Tags: sql, sql-query-store

I have a backend limitation that the Resultant column which is of decimal type(aban) can not have more than 1000 characters in it formula.

How to optimise this query?

I have tried using tempTable but results are not as expected.

```
aban = 
CASE 
WHEN ( 
    sum(isnull(a.callshandled,0)) + sum(isnull(a.totalcallsaband,0)) + sum(isnull(a.incompletecalls,0)) + sum(isnull(a.returnbusy,0)) + sum(isnull(a.returnring,0)) + sum(isnull(a.icrdefaultrouted,0)) + sum(isnull(a.ndr,0)) + sum(isnull(a.overflowout,0)) + sum(isnull(a.callsrona,0)) + sum(isnull(a.returnrelease,0)) + sum(isnull(a.callsroutednonagent,0)) + sum(isnull(a.shortcalls,0)) + sum(isnull(a.agenterrorcount,0)) + sum(isnull(a.errorcount,0))
  ) 
  = 0 THEN 
  0 
  ELSE (sum(isnull(a.totalcallsaband,0)) * 1.0) / (sum(isnull(a.callshandled,0)) + sum(isnull(a.totalcallsaband,0)) + sum(isnull(a.incompletecalls,0)) + sum(isnull(a.returnbusy,0)) + sum(isnull(a.returnring,0)) + sum(isnull(a.icrdefaultrouted,0)) + sum(isnull(a.networkdefaultrouted,0)) + sum(isnull(a.overflowout,0)) + sum(isnull(a.callsrona,0)) + sum(isnull(a.returnrelease,0)) + sum(isnull(a.callsroutednonagent,0)) + sum(isnull(a.shortcalls,0)) + sum(isnull(a.agenterrorcount,0)) + sum(isnull(a.errorcount,0)))
END 
,
```

Optimise the query in such a way that number of characters in formula is less then 1000 and resultant column should have same value before and after query optimisation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a good start when asking SO questions.

Comment: @AbhishekRai . . . You have not shown a *query*.  You have shown an *expression*.  An expression cannot generally be optimized without the context of the query it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

```
DECLARE @dividend int  = 10;
DECLARE @divisor int  = 0;

SELECT COALESCE(@dividend / NULLIF(@divisor,0), 0);
```

So you can avoid duplicate calculation for divisor.